# validating user input on spinner

Tags: android, validation, kotlin, spinner

I am trying to require users to select an item in a spinner before creating an account.
So I am checking if an item is selected using if statement. If not selected, I display to the user a snack message telling them they must select an item. Below is the code:

```
val hearAboutUs =
    if (utmSourcesSpinner.selectedIndex > 0) 1
else 0

if (hearAboutUs == 0) {
    showErrorSnack("You must select where you heard about us.")
}
```

Now when the first item in the spinner is selected, if (utmSourcesSpinner.selectedIndex > 0) 1 else 0 returns false while the rest of the items when selected if (utmSourcesSpinner.selectedIndex > 0) 1 else 0 returns true.

Comment: You get position from onItemSelected() of spinner,if that position is 0 then provide snack else allow to create account.

Answer (score 0):

Spinner.selectedIndex returns index of selected item at first selected item is position 0 so 0 is not > 0 all the Spinners select 0 index at first so you dont need to validate it

Answer (score 0):

spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() returns index of selected item.

```
  int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if (pos > 0) {
        // spinner option is selected
    } else {
        //show toast please select item.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i handle this kind of situation.

Validation button need to check if user selected something from the spinner, by default spinner has a default selected item. This item has a default name like:
"Selecte where you heard about us"

So let's  do it.

1. **First Create spinner in layout**

   ```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/where"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   ```

We have a spinner with entries ( i suppose you already know how customize them, if you need i can explain that)

So spinner allow two method to use them we need import

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

But i prefer crete an objet expression for the spinner, basically i create an object that nherits the class, i do this, because if we have 4 spinner it's to me more easy override for times with object expression

2. **Import the tho methods**

and these are the two methods that ovveride this interface:

where.onItemSelectedListener  = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id:Long) {

            Log.d("test", "user select: ${where[pos]}")
            Log.d("test", "user select: ${where.selectedItem}")
        }

       override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            // Another interface callback
        }
    }
```

where is the id of my spinner, in this method so you can call your validation, or you can make the validation when button login has been clicked, and you can send to another activity the selecte one by taking

```
where.selectedItem.text
```

In any moment it hold the select item

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have used.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener { _, _, _, item ->
        mSelectedItem = item.toString()
    }
if (mSelectedItem.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        showErrorSnack("You must select where you heard about us")
}
```

I have set a listener to the spinner then I have checked if the selected item is null or empty to display the message "you must select where you heard about us"